# Does anyone have a solution for hiding URL html page links from Facebook Iframe tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I have created an HTMl5 template in Facebook using the Static Iframe Tab. I don't really want other admin users - trying to download my content and stealing my work. Is there anywhere I can hide/prevent the URL links appearing for each page? When I hover on items on the Iframe, the URLs appear in the (Firefox) Browser window at the bottom? I would be grateful to know if there is a a way to hide them or prevent them being downloaded (i.e. just allow the the IFrame tab access?)

Answer (score 0):

Not with HTML.  But you could build your website in flash and have much better control over the content and linking.

Comment: I was originally going to use a Flash iframe - but I thought HTML5 Iframe would be viewable on a mobile device (Facebook App or Browser based) but unfortunately it is not and I don't know why :(

Comment: No this did not help as I have been told by the Facebook App owners it is possible with HTML but they are not going to help me out on this

Comment: Really?! Wow. I think the reason they're not helping out with it is because it cannot be done!!   There's no way to hide HTML, otherwise how could the browser render it and if a browser can render it, I can get my hands on it using any modern browser. ....  My suggestion is to setup your own facebook app so you don't have to rely upon the app owners anymore.

Comment: Well after the response from the app owners,  I am thinking of getting someone to develop a Facebook app so I don't have to rely on them anymore. The only question is whether there are possible techniques to mask the html within an Iframe style App?

Comment: Facebook calls iframe apps "Canvas Apps".  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/